# how to integrate a asp webpage to dynamics crm 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

does anyone have a tip/suggestion on how to integrate a asp.net with c# webpage to crm dynamics 2015? I check on the settings under the customization -- customize the system and I look for the web resource and the only thing that I can add is HTML,data(XML), CSS, XAP, Style Sheet (XSL) and ICO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Host your asp.net website on some server (IIS)
2. Add a iframe in CRM form & give that hosted site url

Answer (score 2):

Hopeful below links would help you.

[Implement single sign-on from an ASPX webpage or IFRAME.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx)